# shopify api creates product returns 404

Tags: wordpress, api, shopify

I'm creating a private app that calls the Shopify API from WordPress.  When I make the call to create a new Shopify product, the API creates the product but returns a 404 Not Found error.  I believe I have the code correct because it successfully creates the product and the appropriate success response on a local host on a Windows XP box running apache and PHP 5.2.x.  I have the problem when I run it from a development server running, I assume, Linux, apache and PHP 5.3.x. What would cause the Shopify API to create the product but return a 404?  I'll include a log of the call and response below.  This post did successfully create a product but since it returned an error, I wasn't able to retrieve the newly created product id.

Thanks,
Steve

2012-06-05 @ 17:47:36: request sent to 
https ://xxx:xxx@colab-5.myshopify.com/admin/products.json
Parameters: Array
(
    [method] => POST
    [timeout] => 5
    [redirection] => 5
    [httpversion] => 1.0
    [user-agent] => WordPress/3.3.2; http ://xxx.colab.coop
    [blocking] => 1
    [headers] => Array
        (
        )

```
[cookies] => Array
    (
    )

[body] => Array
    (
        [product] => Array
            (
                [title] => Bracelet 7
                [body_html] => Bracelet 7 descr
                [vendor] => xxx
                [product_type] => bracelet
                [published] => 1
                [images] => Array
                    (
                        [src] => http://xxx.colab.coop/xxx/stb-1.png
                    )

                [variants] => Array
                    (
                        [option1] => small
                        [price] => 123
                        [inventory_management] => shopify
                        [sku] => 234
                        [grams] => 226.79618519019
                        [inventory_quantity] => 123
                    )

            )

    )

[compress] => 
[decompress] => 1
[sslverify] => 1
[stream] => 
[filename] =>
```

)

---

2012-06-05 @ 17:47:37: response received from 
https ://xxx:xxx@colab-5.myshopify.com/admin/products.json
Transport: WP_HTTP_curl
Response: Array
(
    [headers] => Array
        (
            [server] => nginx
            [date] => Tue, 05 Jun 2012 17:47:37 GMT
            [content-type] => text/html; charset=utf-8
            [connection] => close
            [vary] => Accept-Encoding
            [status] => 404 Not Found
            [cache-control] => no-cache
            [x-request-id] => 62c48e7991c1f29cf5917727b160cee9
            [x-ua-compatible] => IE=Edge,chrome=1
            [x-runtime] => 0.025681
        )

```
[body] => <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http 

://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>404 - Not Found</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/assets/dialog-ef6bd71e99b2c7a469ce6385ab855360.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body class="netural-dialog">

  <div id="container">
    <div id="dialog">
      <h1>Not Found</h1>

      <p class="c">The page you were looking for does not exist...</p>



    </div> <!-- dialog -->
  </div> <!-- container -->


  <div id="footer">
    <p><a href="http://www.shopify.com">Ecommerce Software by Shopify</a></p>
  </div>


</body>
</html>

[response] => Array
    (
        [code] => 404
        [message] => Not Found
    )

[cookies] => Array
    (
    )

[filename] =>
```

)

Updating with more logs. This created Shopify product 93781002.

```
*** REQUEST ***
2012-06-08 @ 00:14:20: request sent to 
https://xxx:xxx@colab-5.myshopify.com/admin/products.json
Parameters: Array
(
    [method] => POST
    [timeout] => 5
    [redirection] => 5
    [httpversion] => 1.0
    [user-agent] => WordPress/3.3.2; http://xxx.colab.coop
    [blocking] => 1
    [headers] => Array
        (
            [Content-Type] => application/json; charset=UTF-8
        )

    [cookies] => Array
        (
        )

    [body] => {"product":{"title":"Bracelet 2","body_html":"Bracelet 2 description","vendor":"Steve","product_type":"bracelet","published":true,"images":{"src":"http:\/\/lr.colab.coop\/wordpress\/wp-content\/themes\/lr\/images\/stb-1.png"},"variants":{"option1":"default","price":"123","inventory_management":"shopify","sku":"555","grams":453.59237038038,"inventory_quantity":"22"},"metafields":{"key":"wp_post_id","value":174,"value_type":"string","namespace":"inventory"}}}
    [compress] => 
    [decompress] => 1
    [sslverify] => 
    [stream] => 
    [filename] => 
)

---------------------------------
*** RESPONSE **********
2012-06-08 @ 00:14:21: response received from 
https://xxx:xxx@colab-5.myshopify.com/admin/products.json
Transport: WP_HTTP_curl
Response: Array
(
    [headers] => Array
        (
            [server] => nginx
            [date] => Fri, 08 Jun 2012 00:14:21 GMT
            [content-type] => text/html; charset=utf-8
            [connection] => close
            [vary] => Accept-Encoding
            [status] => 404 Not Found
            [cache-control] => no-cache
            [x-request-id] => ec0ff57554c9deea607c407e00c6c223
            [x-ua-compatible] => IE=Edge,chrome=1
            [x-runtime] => 0.012695
        )

    [body] => <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>404 - Not Found</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/assets/dialog-ef6bd71e99b2c7a469ce6385ab855360.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body class="netural-dialog">

  <div id="container">
    <div id="dialog">
      <h1>Not Found</h1>

      <p class="c">The page you were looking for does not exist...</p>



    </div> <!-- dialog -->
  </div> <!-- container -->


  <div id="footer">
    <p><a href="http://www.shopify.com">Ecommerce Software by Shopify</a></p>
  </div>


</body>
</html>

    [response] => Array
        (
            [code] => 404
            [message] => Not Found
        )

    [cookies] => Array
        (
        )

    [filename] => 
)

---------------------------------
```

Sorry to dump so much content in here but here are new logs for June 13.  The first call successfully created the Shopify product "Office Ring 1" but return an error message. I then manually added the shopify id to my local product and then successfully added a variant, "medium," but that also returned an error message.  These were from a web farm nix server.  Then I ran the same set of requests from the local web server on my Windows laptop.  These requests also successfully created the product "Home Ring 1" but returned appropriate success messages.

```
*** REQUEST ***
2012-06-13 @ 12:18:38: request sent to 
https://removed_aac8:removed_e2ba@colab-5.myshopify.com/admin/products.json
Parameters: Array
(
    [method] => POST
    [timeout] => 5
    [redirection] => 5
    [httpversion] => 1.0
    [user-agent] => WordPress/3.3.2; http://removed.colab.coop
    [blocking] => 1
    [headers] => Array
        (
            [Content-Type] => application/json; charset=UTF-8
        )

    [cookies] => Array
        (
        )

    [body] => {"product":{"title":"Office Ring 1","body_html":"Office Ring 1 description","vendor":"Steve","product_type":"ring","published":true,"variants":{"option1":"small","price":"123","inventory_management":"shopify","sku":"1234","grams":226.79618519019,"inventory_quantity":"10"},"images":{"position":1,"src":"http:\/\/lr.colab.coop\/wordpress\/wp-content\/themes\/lr\/images\/stb-1.png"}}}
    [compress] => 
    [decompress] => 1
    [sslverify] => 
    [stream] => 
    [filename] => 
)

---------------------------------
*** RESPONSE **********
2012-06-13 @ 12:18:40: response received from 
https://removed_aac8:removed_e2ba@colab-5.myshopify.com/admin/products.json
Transport: WP_HTTP_curl
Response: Array
(
    [headers] => Array
        (
            [server] => nginx
            [date] => Wed, 13 Jun 2012 12:18:40 GMT
            [content-type] => text/html; charset=utf-8
            [connection] => close
            [vary] => Accept-Encoding
            [status] => 404 Not Found
            [cache-control] => no-cache
            [x-request-id] => f5ef52645dc28af4993c1378440ad19a
            [x-ua-compatible] => IE=Edge,chrome=1
            [x-runtime] => 0.019331
        )

    [body] => <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>404 - Not Found</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/assets/dialog-ef6bd71e99b2c7a469ce6385ab855360.css?351e96af6f2f2a94c178c053ba0d35a46ec146b4" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body class="netural-dialog">

  <div id="container">
    <div id="dialog">
      <h1>Not Found</h1>

      <p class="c">The page you were looking for does not exist...</p>



    </div> <!-- dialog -->
  </div> <!-- container -->


  <div id="footer">
    <p><a href="http://www.shopify.com">Ecommerce Software by Shopify</a></p>
  </div>


</body>
</html>

    [response] => Array
        (
            [code] => 404
            [message] => Not Found
        )

    [cookies] => Array
        (
        )

    [filename] => 
)

---------------------------------
*** REQUEST ***
2012-06-13 @ 12:22:26: request sent to 
https://removed_aac8:removed_e2ba@colab-5.myshopify.com/admin/products/94072324/variants.json
Parameters: Array
(
    [method] => POST
    [timeout] => 5
    [redirection] => 5
    [httpversion] => 1.0
    [user-agent] => WordPress/3.3.2; http://removed.colab.coop
    [blocking] => 1
    [headers] => Array
        (
            [Content-Type] => application/json; charset=UTF-8
        )

    [cookies] => Array
        (
        )

    [body] => {"variant":{"option1":"medium","price":"123","inventory_management":"shopify","sku":"1235","grams":226.79618519019,"inventory_quantity":"11"}}
    [compress] => 
    [decompress] => 1
    [sslverify] => 
    [stream] => 
    [filename] => 
)

---------------------------------
*** RESPONSE **********
2012-06-13 @ 12:22:27: response received from 
https://removed_aac8:removed_e2ba@colab-5.myshopify.com/admin/products/94072324/variants.json
Transport: WP_HTTP_curl
Response: Array
(
    [headers] => Array
        (
            [server] => nginx
            [date] => Wed, 13 Jun 2012 12:22:27 GMT
            [content-type] => text/html; charset=utf-8
            [connection] => close
            [vary] => Accept-Encoding
            [status] => 200 OK
            [etag] => "450e16059f610a357485485b091697f7"
            [cache-control] => max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
            [x-request-id] => 2ebbec10eefda01f51e06d9d5ed4004f
            [x-ua-compatible] => IE=Edge,chrome=1
            [set-cookie] => _secure_session_id=8efbf69a284bbc7f3652ac6f34e9a2ba; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
            [x-runtime] => 0.025468
            [p3p] => CP="NOI DSP COR NID ADMa OPTa OUR NOR"
        )

    [body] => <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">var NREUMQ=NREUMQ||[];NREUMQ.push(["mark","firstbyte",new Date().getTime()]);</script>
  <title>Shopify &raquo; Please Log In</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/assets/dialog-ef6bd71e99b2c7a469ce6385ab855360.css?351e96af6f2f2a94c178c053ba0d35a46ec146b4" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <!--[if IE 6]>
  <link href="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/assets/ie-e556ea04e7e58d6a732ca8d5254a1edc.css?351e96af6f2f2a94c178c053ba0d35a46ec146b4" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <![endif]-->
  <script src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/assets/admin/auth-0b1f81e1e47d1c2021fc18fe8772a287.js?351e96af6f2f2a94c178c053ba0d35a46ec146b4" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
    if ($('login-input')) {
      if ($('login-input').value == '') { 
        Field.activate('login-input');
      }
      else { 
        Field.activate('password');
      }
    }
  }
  </script>

      <script type="text/javascript">

        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-82702-18' ]);
        _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.myshopify.com']);
        _gaq.push(['_setAllowHash', false]); 
        _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',
            1,                   
            'CustomerType',     
            'prospect',
            2
         ]); 
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

        (function() {
          var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
          ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
          var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();

      </script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="dialog">
      <div id="system_error" class="status system-error"><p>Login or password was invalid.</p></div>

<div class="ssb c">
  <img alt="Shopify-logo-new" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/images/admin/shopify-logo-new.jpg?351e96af6f2f2a94c178c053ba0d35a46ec146b4" />  
</div>

<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/admin/auth/login" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="RSdZQn6QN2MfWeyb6JwkbYKlxi4wxdvLxKEAEuChE/8=" /></div>
<div id="sign-in-form" class="lform">
  <noscript><p>Please note that in order to use the Shopify administration interface you need to <a href="/documents/javascript.html">enable javascript</a>.</p></noscript>

  <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="" id="redirect" />

  <div id="login" >
    <div class="ppb clearfix">
      <label id="email_address" for="login-input">Email Address</label>
      <input type="email" name="login" size="30" id="login-input" class="email" value="" class="error" tabindex=1 />
    </div>
    <div class="ppb clearfix">
      <label id="password_label" for="password">Password</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" size="16" id="password" class="error" tabindex=2 />
      <div id="forgot-password">
        <a href="/admin/auth/recover">Forgot your password?</a>  
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ppb c">
      <input name="remember" type="checkbox" id="remember_checkbox" value="1" />
      <label for="remember_checkbox" class="normal">Remember me on this computer</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="open-id" style="display:none">
    <div class="ppb clearfix">
      <label id="open_id" for="openid-input" class="open-id">OpenID</label>  
      <input type="text" name="openid_url" value="" class="url" id="openid-input" class="error" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <input class="btn" name="commit" tabindex="3" type="submit" value="Sign In" />
  </div>

</div>

</form>


<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {


    $$('input').each(function(e) {
      e.autocapitalize = false;
    });

  });
</script>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <div>
  <span style='padding-left:10px;'>
    <img alt="Google_apps-16" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/images/admin/icons/google_apps-16.png?351e96af6f2f2a94c178c053ba0d35a46ec146b4" /> 
    <a href="/admin/auth/login?google_apps=1">Login with Google Apps</a>
  </span>
</div>



  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">if (!NREUMQ.f) { NREUMQ.f=function() {
NREUMQ.push(["load",new Date().getTime()]);
var e=document.createElement("script");
e.type="text/javascript";e.async=true;e.src="https://d1ros97qkrwjf5.cloudfront.net/38/eum/rum-staging.js";
document.body.appendChild(e);
if(NREUMQ.a)NREUMQ.a();
};
NREUMQ.a=window.onload;window.onload=NREUMQ.f;
};
NREUMQ.push(["nrfj","beacon-1.newrelic.com","fa45dcf839",151,"dl8KQUReDl4AEE1TVVhZChpXRBZaSg4NVVhb",0.0,17,new Date().getTime(),"","","","",""])</script>
</body>
</html>

    [response] => Array
        (
            [code] => 200
            [message] => OK
        )

    [cookies] => Array
        (
            [0] => WP_Http_Cookie Object
                (
                    [name] => _secure_session_id
                    [value] => 8efbf69a284bbc7f3652ac6f34e9a2ba
                    [expires] => 
                    [path] => /
                    [domain] => 
                    [secure] => 
                    [httponly] => 
                )

        )

    [filename] => 
)

---------------------------------
```

And now the successful Home logs

```
*** REQUEST ***
2012-06-13 @ 12:27:40: request sent to 
https://removed_aac8:removed_e2ba@colab-5.myshopify.com/admin/products.json
Parameters: Array
(
    [method] => POST
    [timeout] => 5
    [redirection] => 5
    [httpversion] => 1.0
    [user-agent] => WordPress/3.3.2; http://localhost/knowledgetown/office/wordpress
    [blocking] => 1
    [headers] => Array
        (
            [Content-Type] => application/json; charset=UTF-8
        )

    [cookies] => Array
        (
        )

    [body] => {"product":{"title":"Home Ring 1","body_html":"Home Ring 1 description","vendor":"Auto Draft","product_type":"ring","published":true,"variants":{"option1":"small","price":"123","inventory_management":"shopify","sku":"1234","grams":226.79618519019,"inventory_quantity":"10"},"images":{"position":1,"src":"http:\/\/lr.colab.coop\/wordpress\/wp-content\/themes\/lr\/images\/stb-1.png"}}}
    [compress] => 
    [decompress] => 1
    [sslverify] => 
    [stream] => 
    [filename] => 
)

---------------------------------
*** RESPONSE **********
2012-06-13 @ 12:27:41: response received from 
https://removed_aac8:removed_e2ba@colab-5.myshopify.com/admin/products.json
Transport: WP_HTTP_curl
Response: Array
(
    [headers] => Array
        (
            [server] => nginx
            [date] => Wed, 13 Jun 2012 12:27:40 GMT
            [content-type] => application/json; charset=utf-8
            [connection] => close
            [status] => 201 Created
            [x-shopify-shop-api-call-limit] => 1/500
            [http_x_shopify_shop_api_call_limit] => 1/500
            [location] => https://colab-5.myshopify.com/admin/products/94072592
            [cache-control] => no-cache
            [x-request-id] => 36b9127191967ed4bf9b2039eb651790
            [x-ua-compatible] => IE=Edge,chrome=1
            [set-cookie] => _secure_session_id=15d92980d403a103a3e8da29a33c8e7f; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
            [x-runtime] => 0.585917
        )

    [body] => {"product":{"body_html":"Home Ring 1 description","created_at":"2012-06-13T08:27:40-04:00","handle":"home-ring-1","id":94072592,"product_type":"ring","published_at":"2012-06-13T08:27:40-04:00","template_suffix":null,"title":"Home Ring 1","updated_at":"2012-06-13T08:27:40-04:00","vendor":"Auto Draft","tags":"","variants":[{"compare_at_price":null,"created_at":"2012-06-13T08:27:40-04:00","fulfillment_service":"manual","grams":226,"id":220076798,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","option1":"small","option2":null,"option3":null,"position":1,"price":"123.00","product_id":94072592,"requires_shipping":true,"sku":"1234","taxable":true,"title":"small","updated_at":"2012-06-13T08:27:40-04:00","inventory_quantity":10}],"images":[{"created_at":"2012-06-13T08:27:40-04:00","id":187968224,"position":1,"product_id":94072592,"updated_at":"2012-06-13T08:27:40-04:00","src":"http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0157/0142/products/stb-2.png?241"}],"options":[{"name":"Title"}]}}
    [response] => Array
        (
            [code] => 201
            [message] => Created
        )

    [cookies] => Array
        (
            [0] => WP_Http_Cookie Object
                (
                    [name] => _secure_session_id
                    [value] => 15d92980d403a103a3e8da29a33c8e7f
                    [expires] => 
                    [path] => /
                    [domain] => 
                    [secure] => 
                    [httponly] => 
                )

        )

    [filename] => 
)

---------------------------------
*** REQUEST ***
2012-06-13 @ 12:28:13: request sent to 
https://removed_aac8:removed_e2ba@colab-5.myshopify.com/admin/products/94072592/variants.json
Parameters: Array
(
    [method] => POST
    [timeout] => 5
    [redirection] => 5
    [httpversion] => 1.0
    [user-agent] => WordPress/3.3.2; http://localhost/knowledgetown/office/wordpress
    [blocking] => 1
    [headers] => Array
        (
            [Content-Type] => application/json; charset=UTF-8
        )

    [cookies] => Array
        (
        )

    [body] => {"variant":{"option1":"medium","price":"123","inventory_management":"shopify","sku":"1235","grams":226.79618519019,"inventory_quantity":"11"}}
    [compress] => 
    [decompress] => 1
    [sslverify] => 
    [stream] => 
    [filename] => 
)

---------------------------------
*** RESPONSE **********
2012-06-13 @ 12:28:13: response received from 
https://removed_aac8:removed_e2ba@colab-5.myshopify.com/admin/products/94072592/variants.json
Transport: WP_HTTP_curl
Response: Array
(
    [headers] => Array
        (
            [server] => nginx
            [date] => Wed, 13 Jun 2012 12:28:13 GMT
            [content-type] => application/json; charset=utf-8
            [connection] => close
            [status] => 201 Created
            [x-shopify-shop-api-call-limit] => 4/500
            [http_x_shopify_shop_api_call_limit] => 4/500
            [location] => https://colab-5.myshopify.com/admin/products/94072592/variants
            [cache-control] => no-cache
            [x-request-id] => fd0cfb4f0279424a850d6bf100533f1d
            [x-ua-compatible] => IE=Edge,chrome=1
            [set-cookie] => _secure_session_id=63dd9cc4fcd51eacb0a792ffb148de5e; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
            [x-runtime] => 0.069807
        )

    [body] => {"variant":{"compare_at_price":null,"created_at":"2012-06-13T08:28:13-04:00","fulfillment_service":"manual","grams":226,"id":220076802,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","option1":"medium","option2":null,"option3":null,"position":2,"price":"123.00","product_id":94072592,"requires_shipping":true,"sku":"1235","taxable":true,"title":"medium","updated_at":"2012-06-13T08:28:13-04:00","inventory_quantity":11}}
    [response] => Array
        (
            [code] => 201
            [message] => Created
        )

    [cookies] => Array
        (
            [0] => WP_Http_Cookie Object
                (
                    [name] => _secure_session_id
                    [value] => 63dd9cc4fcd51eacb0a792ffb148de5e
                    [expires] => 
                    [path] => /
                    [domain] => 
                    [secure] => 
                    [httponly] => 
                )

        )

    [filename] => 
)

---------------------------------
```

Comment: What happens if you drop the URL you're calling into a browser? Does it return a list of products or a 404?

Answer (score 2):

The logs for that request say that you were calling `POST "/admin/products/PRODUCT_ID"`. Check your code to make sure it's doing what you think. Note that all API calls should have a type suffix, so a valid URL would be `/admin/products/PRODUCT_ID.json` or `/admin/products/PRODUCT_ID.xml`

Comment: It should also looks like the content type header isn't being passed in either. [headers] => Array ( [Content-Type] => "application/json" ) should be included as well.

Comment: That url in a browser returns a list of products. My calls all end with .json. My GETs all work. I added the Content-Type to the headers. I verified that this was being included by using requestb.in. Still 404. If I run that same code on my home computer (Windows XP, apache, PHP 5.2.x) the request returns a 201 Created. If I run the code on a web farm server (I assume running Linux, apache, PHP 5.3.x) I get the 404.  Even when I get the 404, the product is still created in Shopify. I'm looking for something that would be different between home and farm like encoding or another header setting.

Comment: Could you try adding the [Accept] => "application/json" header as well.  I'm not too sure what could be causing the problem.  Sometimes it's just missing headers that causes stuff like this.

Comment: I now see that my GET requests are broken too. I undid the last change and they are still broken so I must have broken it somewhere else. I'll need to fix that before I declare that the last suggestion didn't work.

Comment: Fixed the GET requests.  Adding 'Accept' to the headers doesn't change the behavior when trying to add a product.  However it makes adding a variant worse.  I have been able to add variants.  Adding a variant returns a 200 but it also returns content for a Shopify Login page. I ignore that.  When I add the 'Accept' parameter to the header I get a 401 Unauthorized when trying to add a variant.  The variant is successfully added in Shopify, it is the return message that is the problem.

Comment: David - I sure would like to resolve this. I just edited the original post to add new logs from today. Can you compare them with Shopify's logs and see if you can figure out what is different between the two or why the ones that create "Office Ring 1" and the subsequent variant successfully create the product but return a failure notice?

Comment: You've posted the same set of data twice in your question (the non-working ones). Please update it so that the second set shows the correct requests.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've replaced the second set of logs with the real home logs that were successful.

Comment: There's something fishy going on with your server logs. The requested URLs for those request IDs in my logs do not match the ones in your logs. The ones in your home logs do match up. In your first set of logs, you're not requesting what you think you're requesting, hence the errors.

Comment: These are logs I have created in WordPress...not technically server logs.  Looking through the WP core code I thought this had to be what was submitted but apparently something is changing.  What URLs are being submitted? Knowing what is getting changed will likely help me track it down.

Comment: First one: POST /admin/products/94072324 Second one: POST /admin/auth/login

Comment: Solved! I changed the 'redirects' part of the request from 5 to 0 assuming that if I got the same old 404 error that meant the problem was on my server and that if I got a 'too many redirects' error that meant the problem was on Shopify's server. To my surprise I got a 201 Created success response. I assume that there has been (and still is) a mild problem with my request and, if allowed to redirect, the Shopify server would do so and send back a 404 error.